# c# Server role with multi type clients

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, client, server

I'm trying to built a server client application (wpf).

the structure I'm trying to accomplish is this:

1. a client that only sends data( a simple string) needs to be a wpf app.
2. a client that only receives data(a string from the sender client)
3. a server that transfer the data from the sender to the receiver (can be multiple senders and multiple receivers) can be a console
   application.

One of the problems I'm facing is how do I separate the server role.

The second problem is how do I let the server know what type of client it's communicating with, a sender or a receiver.

this is my code:

---

Server:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;

namespace NetMessageServerWpf
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        TcpClient client;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 3000);
            this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
            this.listenThread.Start();
        }

        private void btnSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(client == null || !client.Connected)
                client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            msg = txtMessage.Text;
            SendTCP(client);
        }

        public TcpListener tcpListener;
        public Thread listenThread;

        private string msg;

        private void ListenForClients()
        {
            this.tcpListener.Start();
        }

        public void SendTCP(TcpClient tcpClient)
        {
            NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes(this.msg);
            clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            clientStream.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
namespace NetClientSideWpf
{
    class Client : Base
    {

        private string messageString;
        public string MessageString
        {
            get { return messageString; }
            set
            {
                messageString = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MessageString");
            }
        }


        public Client()
        {
            ConnectToServer();
        }

        public void ConnectToServer()
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

            IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 3000);

            client.Connect(serverEndPoint);


            NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();

            Thread ServerThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
            ServerThread.Start(client);


        }

        private void HandleClientComm(object client)
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
            NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

            byte[] message = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;

            while (true)
            {
                bytesRead = 0;

                try
                {
                    bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
                }
                catch
                {
                    break;
                }

                if (bytesRead == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
                MessageString = encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I don't understand your first question, it seems like you have already separated the server. As to the second, the *clients* know if they are senders/recievers, correct?

Comment: as for my first question, the server I have now is acting in both roles, being a server and a sender. I want the server to accept data from the sender and transfer it to all the receivers (like a streamer but I want to use tcp and not udp of course). as for my 2nd question, aye the client knows what type it is. (I wont create a send button on the receiver client's gui anyway)

Comment: Ok, do senders also receive other sent messages, or do the senders just send? I can answer (at least in broad strokes) once I know that.

Comment: well at this point I want the senders to only send data but I don't mind that they will receive data from the server (but only certain data like status of message sent / message received) but this feature can be added along the way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I would wrap your clients in a `Client` object that you can call methods on.

Then, when a client connects, it should send out a message detailing its mode:

> "IAm:Sender"
>
> OR
>
> "IAm:Reciever"

You could have the second part parse to an `enum` if you wanted. Then you would sort the `Client` objects based on the mode:

```
List<Client> clients;

client.Mode = Enum.Parse(typeof(ClientMode), message.Split(':')[1]);
clients.Add(client);
```

And when a "sender" sent a "Broadcast" message, you would write it to every `Client` object in the `recievers` list. This would be in the client read thread

```
if (sender.Type == ClientMode.Sender)
{
    foreach (Client client in clients.Where(c => c.Type == ClientMode.Sender)
        client.Send(message)
}
```

Obviously these are very broad strokes, and the full implementation would be far too large for SO. Hopefully that gets you on the right track, please let me know if I can clarify anything!

Comment: thanks, this is something I had in mind but I'm having trouble to implement it. I'm not used to work with threads and TCP. this is a new area for me.

Comment: @Sag1v anything in particular you are having trouble with? Did my answer make sense?

Comment: well, what I had in mind is to add a "Type" property to the client and in the string that it sends give it a special flag that the server can parse. but what I don't understand is how do I make the server do that, and how do I make the server receive a message and automatically send it to the receivers list.

Comment: @Sag1v I tried to provide simple (though not complete) examples of how to do those things. Does that help?

Comment: thanks. so basically I have 1 client class and 1 server class(a different project even)... can you show me how your code works on my code please?

Comment: @Sag1v I'm not sure what you are asking. All the code I have posted is on the server side. Creating the clients is simply a matter of sending the correct messages.

Comment: i will try your suggestion and let you know. I think i understand your point but not sure. I just thought of another issue, i need to handle a disconnected clients as well.

Comment: @Sag1v Thats simple enough, `TcpClient` raises an event on disconnect IIRC. Then you just remove from the list. Come chat in C# or WPF if you want to talk more about it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66796/discussion-between-sag1v-and-bradleydotnet).